# Difference in day between date i have passed in query and field date of table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have History Table of points Earned as below

```
ID      Points      earn_date
1       10          2017-04-04
2       8           2017-04-01  
3       12          2017-04-28
4       7           2017-05-16
5       9           2017-06-03
```

Now From earn_date till today date i want to get the days difference using query

First I have Tried with following Query

```
SELECT *,earn_date - '2017-06-17' AS RemainDays FROM customer_earning
```

then i have tried with `DATEDIFF` Function but didn't get the result

How can i get the days result

Output i want is if i pass today date then

```
ID      Points      earn_date      Days
1       10          2017-04-04     74
2       8           2017-04-01     78
3       12          2017-04-28     50
4       7           2017-05-16     32
```

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: Show what you tried with datediff and what you got as result from this

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do what you want?

```
SELECT ce.*, DATEDIFF('2017-06-17', ce.earn_date) AS RemainDays
FROM customer_earning ce;
```

Given the information in the question, this should calculate the remaining days.

You could be explicit about the type casts, but I doubt that will make a difference:

```
SELECT ce.*,
       DATEDIFF(DATE('2017-06-17'), DATE(ce.earn_date)) AS RemainDays
FROM customer_earning ce;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below query:

```
select *,DATEDIFF(day,Earn_Date,GETDATE()) as RemainDays FROM customer_earning
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Query

```
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate) AS RemainDays FROM customer_earning;
```

For Example :

```
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),earn_date) AS RemainDays FROM customer_earning;
```

**startdate:** like Today Date **[GETDATE()]**
**enddate:** like *earn_date*

**[datepart]** is like what do you want to calculate. for example if you want to calculate days, date part is **day**, if you want to calculate months, date part is **month**